# how can it be proved that $\text{Log}|z-z_0|$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I know it can be proved in almost all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$, (exept the straight line from $z_0$ parallel to $[-\infty,0]$), as the real part of the holomorphic function $\text{Log}(z-z_0)$.

Comment: Did you mean "analytic" instead of "harmonic"? If so, simply use that composition of analytic is analytic (provided everything is in the right domain).

Comment: In *any* disk in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$ you can choose an holomorphic branch of the logarithm, and its real part is $\log |z-z_0|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Any* holomorphic branch of $\log(z-z_0)$ in some domain $D$ satisfies
  $$
  \begin{align}
   &z-z_0 = e^{\log(z-z_0)} \\
  \implies& |z-z_0| = e^{\operatorname{Re} \log(z-z_0)} \\
  \implies& \log|z-z_0| = \operatorname{Re} \bigl(\log(z-z_0)\bigr)
  \end{align}
  $$
  in $D$, not only the principal part.
- Every point in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$ has a neighborhood (e.g. a disk) in which a holomorphic branch of  $\log(z-z_0)$ exists.

Combining these two facts we can conclude that $\log|z-z_0|$ is harmonic everywhere in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z_0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Can also just calculate the Laplacian directly using $\ln |z| = \frac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+y^2)$. Or use the complex form of the Laplacian, $\frac 1 4 \frac{d^2}{dzd\bar{z}}$ on $\ln |z| = \frac 1 2 \ln z \bar{z} = \frac 1 2 \ln z + \frac 1 2 \ln \bar{z}$.